# unble to get property "includes" of undefined or null reference

Tags: reactjs, webpack, microsoft-edge

I have build my application in Reactjs and I tried to open the application on Microsoft Edge browser.
I am getting the below error,
unable to get property "includes" of undefined or null reference.

Unable to load the page

Comment: provide code snippet

Comment: What version of Edge? Includes may not be supported https://caniuse.com/#search=includes

Comment: Whether it works well on another browser (such as chrome and IE browser)? Try to use F12 developer tools to debug the code. Besides, can you post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I installed one npm package,
 https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-app-polyfill.
With the help of this I am able to run my app on edge but it still not working on IE 11

Comment: I am getting SCRIPT1002: Syntax error for the below line in the bundle.js 
**return email.split('\0').map((part) => part.normalize('NFC')).join('\0');**

Answer (score 2):

> I installed one npm package, npmjs.com/package/react-app-polyfill.
>   With the help of this I am able to run my app on edge but it still not
>   working on IE 11

Please refer to the following steps to make the react application works well on IE 11 browser.

1. Install the package using Yarn or npm:  (since, you have already installed this package, please ignore this step)

   ```
   npm install react-app-polyfill
   ```

   or

   ```
   yarn add react-app-polyfill
   ```
2. Add the following code on the first line in 'src/index.js'.

   ```
   import 'react-app-polyfill/ie11';
   import 'react-app-polyfill/stable';
   ```
3. Add ie 11 in 'packge.json' like this:

   [image]
4. Restart the app and it will work in IE11.

Comment: I am getting SCRIPT1002: Syntax error for the below line in the  bundle.js

**return email.split('\0').map((part) => part.normalize('NFC')).join('\0');**

Comment: Are you sure that `/stable` exists? I got this error.
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-app-polyfill/stable'

Comment: @Madeo I had the same issue you need to update your react-app-polyfill at least to 1.0.0 version.